# ConTeXt: vertical spacing

Tags: context

I'm a bit confused about how to specify vertical whitespace. The following document works:

```
\setupwhitespace[line]
\setuphead[subsection]   [after={\blank[2*line]}]

\starttext

\subsection{Title}

\input tufte

\input tufte

\stoptext
```

But why can't I use `\setupwhitespace[2*line]`, and neither `\blank[0.5*line]`? Both result in an error. Meanwhile, `\setupwhitespace[5cm]` doesn't seem to have an effect.

What I'm actually trying to achieve is having the vertical spacing between paragraphs (and subsections) `0.5*line`, or if that's not possible some specific centimeters.

Comment: [``\setupwhitespace[halfline]``](http://www.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2011/057651.html), also see [``\installwhitespacemethod``](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/refs/heads/origin:/tex/context/base/spac-ver.mkiv#l386).

Comment: Thanks, `halfline` works. But what about, say `0.1*line`? Pasting `\installwhitespacemethod \v!pointoneline {\s_spac_whitespace_parskip.1\baselineskip}` gives an error.

Comment: Enclose the installwhitespace line in `\starttexcode … \stoptexcode` and replace `\v!pointoneline` with `{pointoneline}`.

Comment: okay, seems I'm starting to figure it out (feel free to edit my answer below). So the only missing case would be: `0.1*line` spacing after a subsection. Is that possible as well?

Comment: `\setuphead[section][style=\tfc, before={\blank[line]}, after={\blank[none]}]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A clean way, which doesn't require low level TeX is to use the measure
mechanism. A dimension is defined using `\definemeasure`, the value can be
retrieved with `\measure`.

```
\definemeasure
  [pointoneline]
  [.5\baselineskip]

\setupwhitespace
  [\measure{pointoneline}]

\setuphead
  [subsection]
  [after={\blank[\measure{pointoneline}]}]

\starttext
  \startsubsection [title=Title]
    \input knuth
  \stopsubsection
\stoptext
```

[image: result]